# Getting "globals is not defined" error when globals variable is clearly defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm currently in the process of reorganizing the routes in my web application (I stupidly defined all the routes in index.js) and for some reason in several of these files I'm having this inexplicable problem: I'm getting errors saying the "globals" variable is undefined when it is, in fact, defined.

This is one of the offending files:

http://pastebin.com/7Q5ExZDa

At line 37 I log the contents of globals.DB_URL, and it exists. The very next line I get an error that globals isn't defined. What am I doing wrong?

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/[redacted_db_name] // console log output
--- Error: ReferenceError: globals is not defined ---
 Location: function (err){
            utilities.logError(err, arguments.callee.toString());
            res.redirect("/");
            return;
        }
```

UPDATE:
First problem was solved: I wasn't importing globals.js in utilities.js, and was trying to call a function that needed data from globals to function.

Unfortunately, now I get this error:

```
--- Error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'connect' of undefined ---
 Location: function (err){
            utilities.logError(err, arguments.callee.toString());
            res.redirect("/");
            return;
        }
```

This error happens at the second promise. I think it may have something to do with the code in utilities, specifically the identifyUserByToken function.

```
/**
* identifyUserByToken
* Compares a given session token against the session tokens collection
* executes a given callback function if a match is found
* @param {String} userToken The session token to search for
* @param {function(Object, String)} The callback function to be called upon success, failure, or error
*/
function identifyUserByToken(userToken, callback){
    var user_tokens;
    var users
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        mongoClient.connect(globals.DB_URL)
            .then(function(db){ // Search user_tokens for userToken
                user_tokens = db.collection("user_tokens");
                users = db.collection("users");
                return user_tokens.find({token : userToken}).toArray();
            })
            .then(function(result){ // Search users for the returned userID
                var userID = result[0].userid;
                return users.find({ userid : userID }).toArray();
            })
            .then(function(matchingUsers){ // Pass returned user object to callback
                var user = matchingUsers[0];
                if(callback != undefined) callback(undefined, user);
                resolve(user);
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                if(callback != undefined) callback(err, undefined);
                reject(err);
            });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

I know this means mongodb is undefined, but I'm importing it in the file

```
    var globals = require("./globals");

    /* == Third Party Libraries == */
    var chalk = require("chalk"); /* usage: console output coloring */
    var crypto = require("crypto"); /* usage: cryptograpgic primitives (password hashing, etc...) */
    var mongodb = require("mongodb"); /* usage: data storage schema */

    var mongoClient = mongodb.mongoClient;
```

EDIT: Solved TypeError

Simple typo. In utilities I was assigning the mongoClient variable incorrectly

How it was being defined: `var mongoClient = mongodb.mongoClient;`

How it needed to be defined: `var mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;`

Sorry! My bad.

Comment: what would happen if you did `var url = globals.DB_URL` and then log the url value and pass it to `mongoClient.connect(url)` ?

Comment: @uglycode prints the url and then I get another ReferenceError: globals is not defined.

Comment: perhaps i didnt understand you right: you said that at line 37 the console.log displays the correct value? so if you do `var url = globals.DB_URL` before line 37 and `console.log(url);` do you get the same result?

Comment: @uglycode Yeah, exact same thing.

Comment: And if you then pass `url` variable to connect function you get the same error that globals is not defined even though you passed `url` variable?

Comment: @uglycode I solved the problem (partially). I wasn't importing globals in utilities, and was trying to use a utilities function that needed a variable from globals. New problem, though, now I get this error. `--- Error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'connect' of undefined ---`

Comment: That means that mongoClient is not defined. Perhaps you didn't include it (right). The point is, there is no mongoClient

Comment: @uglycode I'm importing mongodb and defining mongoClient in the file.

Comment: I'm just guessing but shouldn't it be MongoClient. With a capital M?

Comment: @uglycode Yeah I just realized, sorry about that. My code is being plagued by typos as I break it up into multiple files that need redundant imports and such. Valuable lesson to be learned here: I shouldn't have lazily stuck everything in index.js because "I can fix it later", because "fixing it later" is a much bigger pain than I expected it to be.

Comment: Was that the source of your problems? Or are you still experiencing issues?

Comment: @uglycode No more issues. I think I need to rethink the way I log errors, though; It really wasn't clear that the problem was coming from an external file.

Comment: Good to hear it! I'll write an official answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with  `var mongoClient = mongodb.mongoClient;` it should be with a capital M:

`var mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;`